# Varying number of elements in scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

How do I tell my program how to vary how many elements are to be read by `scanf`? I want it to read each character in a string, and the length of the string may vary from one character to a hundred characters. I know I can do `scanf("%c%c%c%c...")` a hundred times but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: The purpose of the program is to add each integer value of the characters of a string and find the sum without using arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, use `fgets()` with an appropriately sized buffer:

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
    // input is now in `buf'
}
```

If you really can't use arrays, then call `getchar()` until it finds a newline:

```
int sum = 0;

int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
    sum += ch;
}
```

(this already does what you want, i. e. it sums the character codes of the string the user enters.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
char A[105];
scanf("%s", A);
printf("%s\n", A);
```

By this, you can input string with various length. If you input "abc" then the result is "abc"

Comment: Please don't use `scanf()` for inputting arbitrary-length strings. `fgets()` is a much better alternative.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without arrays?

Comment: unfortunately no. Usually I use this for input string

Comment: @asdfqwer In theory, you can call `getchar()` repeatedly, but that's quite inconvenient. But I'll update my answer.

Comment: @david "no" is wrong. Also, do yourself (and your users) a favor and start using `fgets()` for getting user input. `scanf()` is unsafe and counter-intuitive.

Comment: @asdfqwer: Why are you jumping through hoops to avoid having to use arrays? you'll have to use them sooner or later. Best get used to them now...